# Two columns with multicol and minipage in the right column: Why are the pictures shown so deformed?

Tags: minipage, multicol

I have the following problem.

I have a multicol{2} document (a poster) and in the right column I would like to draw to tikzpictures that then are besides each other.

Unfortunately the pictures are shown very small and not completely: This is how they look like in the right columns of my multicol{2} document:

[image]

and this is how they look and are supposed to look when I draw them in a normal document without two columns:

[image]

This is the Code I use:

```
\documentclass[a0,portrait]{a0poster}

\usepackage{multicol} 
\columnsep=100pt 
\columnseprule=3pt 
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{times} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\graphicspath{{figures/}} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} 
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb} 
\usepackage{wrapfig} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,lipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 

\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{algorithmicx,algorithm}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,automata,arrows,positioning,calc}
\usepackage{ulem}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{algor}{%
  \hrulefill\par\offinterlineskip\vskip1pt%
    \textbf{#1#2}#3\offinterlineskip\hrulefill}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{algori}{singlelinecheck=off,format=algor,labelsep=space}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\title{Poster}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1}
\setcounter{subsection}{1}

% Shorthands
\newcommand*\iffdef{\overset{\text{def}}{\iff}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}

% Theorem
\mdtheorem[
  linecolor=NavyBlue,
  frametitlefont=\sffamily\bfseries\color{white},
  frametitlebackgroundcolor=NavyBlue,
]{Def}{Theorem}

\begin{multicols}{2}

text

 \begin{figure}[H]
 \centering
  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.45\columnwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current axis.south)]
\begin{axis}
[
xlabel = $x$,
ylabel = $f_r(x)$,
samples = 300,
domain = 0.9:1.4,
%ymin= -10,
ymax = 40,
legend style = {anchor = north west, at = {(5.05,1)}}
]
\addplot[thick,red]{x^3-x^2-1}
node[above,sloped,pos=0.85] {$r=1$};

\addplot[thick,blue]{x^12-x^11-1}
node[above,sloped,pos=0.5] {$r=10$};

\addplot[thick,magenta]{x^17-x^16-1}
node[above,sloped,pos=0.3] {$r=15$};

\addplot[thick,green]{x^22-x^21-1}
node[above,sloped,pos=0.06] {$r=20$};

\addplot[thick,cyan]{x^27-x^26-1}
node[above,sloped,pos=0.0126]{$r=25$};

\draw[loosely dotted] (0,0) -- (1.4,0);
\draw[dotted] (1,0) -- (1,40);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

    \subcaption{$f_r(x), x\in [0.9,1.4]$, for increasing $r$}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[c]{.45\columnwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current axis.south)]
  \begin{axis}
    [xmin=.9,xmax=2,
      ymax=1,
      ymin=-.1,
      xlabel = $x$
    ]
    \addplot[thick,black,samples=100,domain=0:2] {x^2 - x}
    node[above,sloped,pos=.5] {$x^2 - x$}
    ;
    \addplot[thick,red,samples=100,domain=1:2]  {1/x}
    node[above,sloped,pos=.4] {$r=1$}
    ;
    \addplot[thick,blue,samples=100,domain=.99:2]  {1/x^10}
    node[above,sloped,pos=.3] {$r=10$}
    ;
    \addplot[thick,teal,samples=200,domain=.99:2]  {1/x^50}
    node[above,sloped,pos=.52] {$r=50$}
    ;
    \addplot[thick,brown,samples=300,domain=.99:2]  {1/x^200}
    ;
    \node[brown,rotate=270] at (axis cs:.96,.2) {$r=200$};
    \draw [black, fill=white]  (1.46557,0.682325) circle (3pt) node[right] {$I_1$};
    \draw [black, fill=white]  (1.17295,0.202862) circle (3pt) node[right] {$I_{10}$};
    \draw [black, fill=white]  (1.05757,0.060884) circle (3pt) node[right] {$I_{50}$};
    \draw [black, fill=white]  (1.03,0.035) circle (3pt) node[below] {$I_{200}$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \subcaption{Intersection points $I_r=(\rho_r,g_1(\rho_r))$ of $g_1(x):=x^2-x$ and $g_2(x):=x^{-r}$ for increasing $r$}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{$\rho_r\to 1$ as $r\to\infty$}
\end{figure}



\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

What do I have to change?

---

modified example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a0,portrait]{a0poster}

\usepackage{multicol} 
\columnsep=100pt 
\columnseprule=3pt 
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\title{Poster}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1}
\setcounter{subsection}{1}

% Shorthands

% Theorem

\begin{multicols}{2}

text

 \begin{figure}[H]
 \centering
  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.45\columnwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current axis.south)]
\begin{axis}
[
xlabel = $x$,
ylabel = $f_r(x)$,
samples = 300,
domain = 0.9:1.4,
%ymin= -10,
ymax = 40,
legend style = {anchor = north west, at = {(5.05,1)}}
]
\addplot[thick,red]{x^3-x^2-1}
node[above,sloped,pos=0.85] {$r=1$};

\addplot[thick,blue]{x^12-x^11-1}
node[above,sloped,pos=0.5] {$r=10$};

\addplot[thick,magenta]{x^17-x^16-1}
node[above,sloped,pos=0.3] {$r=15$};

\addplot[thick,green]{x^22-x^21-1}
node[above,sloped,pos=0.06] {$r=20$};

\addplot[thick,cyan]{x^27-x^26-1}
node[above,sloped,pos=0.0126]{$r=25$};

\draw[loosely dotted] (0,0) -- (1.4,0);
\draw[dotted] (1,0) -- (1,40);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

    \caption{$f_r(x), x\in [0.9,1.4]$, for increasing $r$}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[c]{.45\columnwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current axis.south)]
  \begin{axis}
    [xmin=.9,xmax=2,
      ymax=1,
      ymin=-.1,
      xlabel = $x$
    ]
    \addplot[thick,black,samples=100,domain=0:2] {x^2 - x}
    node[above,sloped,pos=.5] {$x^2 - x$}
    ;
    \addplot[thick,red,samples=100,domain=1:2]  {1/x}
    node[above,sloped,pos=.4] {$r=1$}
    ;
    \addplot[thick,blue,samples=100,domain=.99:2]  {1/x^10}
    node[above,sloped,pos=.3] {$r=10$}
    ;
    \addplot[thick,teal,samples=200,domain=.99:2]  {1/x^50}
    node[above,sloped,pos=.52] {$r=50$}
    ;
    \addplot[thick,brown,samples=300,domain=.99:2]  {1/x^200}
    ;
    \node[brown,rotate=270] at (axis cs:.96,.2) {$r=200$};
    \draw [black, fill=white]  (1.46557,0.682325) circle (3pt) node[right] {$I_1$};
    \draw [black, fill=white]  (1.17295,0.202862) circle (3pt) node[right] {$I_{10}$};
    \draw [black, fill=white]  (1.05757,0.060884) circle (3pt) node[right] {$I_{50}$};
    \draw [black, fill=white]  (1.03,0.035) circle (3pt) node[below] {$I_{200}$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Intersection points $I_r=(\rho_r,g_1(\rho_r))$ of $g_1(x):=x^2-x$ and $g_2(x):=x^{-r}$ for increasing $r$}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{$\rho_r\to 1$ as $r\to\infty$}
\end{figure}



\end{multicols}

\hrule

    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current axis.south)]
\begin{axis}
[
xlabel = $x$,
ylabel = $f_r(x)$,
samples = 300,
domain = 0.9:1.4,
%ymin= -10,
ymax = 40,
legend style = {anchor = north west, at = {(5.05,1)}}
]
\addplot[thick,red]{x^3-x^2-1}
node[above,sloped,pos=0.85] {$r=1$};

\addplot[thick,blue]{x^12-x^11-1}
node[above,sloped,pos=0.5] {$r=10$};

\addplot[thick,magenta]{x^17-x^16-1}
node[above,sloped,pos=0.3] {$r=15$};

\addplot[thick,green]{x^22-x^21-1}
node[above,sloped,pos=0.06] {$r=20$};

\addplot[thick,cyan]{x^27-x^26-1}
node[above,sloped,pos=0.0126]{$r=25$};

\draw[loosely dotted] (0,0) -- (1.4,0);
\draw[dotted] (1,0) -- (1,40);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current axis.south)]
  \begin{axis}
    [xmin=.9,xmax=2,
      ymax=1,
      ymin=-.1,
      xlabel = $x$
    ]
    \addplot[thick,black,samples=100,domain=0:2] {x^2 - x}
    node[above,sloped,pos=.5] {$x^2 - x$}
    ;
    \addplot[thick,red,samples=100,domain=1:2]  {1/x}
    node[above,sloped,pos=.4] {$r=1$}
    ;
    \addplot[thick,blue,samples=100,domain=.99:2]  {1/x^10}
    node[above,sloped,pos=.3] {$r=10$}
    ;
    \addplot[thick,teal,samples=200,domain=.99:2]  {1/x^50}
    node[above,sloped,pos=.52] {$r=50$}
    ;
    \addplot[thick,brown,samples=300,domain=.99:2]  {1/x^200}
    ;
    \node[brown,rotate=270] at (axis cs:.96,.2) {$r=200$};
    \draw [black, fill=white]  (1.46557,0.682325) circle (3pt) node[right] {$I_1$};
    \draw [black, fill=white]  (1.17295,0.202862) circle (3pt) node[right] {$I_{10}$};
    \draw [black, fill=white]  (1.05757,0.060884) circle (3pt) node[right] {$I_{50}$};
    \draw [black, fill=white]  (1.03,0.035) circle (3pt) node[below] {$I_{200}$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

Here is the Code for which it works:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{latexsym} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{bbold} 
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{algorithmicx,algorithm}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,automata,arrows,positioning,calc}
\usepackage{ulem}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{algor}{%
  \hrulefill\par\offinterlineskip\vskip1pt%
    \textbf{#1#2}#3\offinterlineskip\hrulefill}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{algori}{singlelinecheck=off,format=algor,labelsep=space}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{style=algori}

\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\title{title}
\author{name}
\date{\today}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \centering
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current axis.south)]
\begin{axis}
[
xlabel = $x$,
ylabel = $f_r(x)$,
samples = 300,
domain = 0.9:1.4,
%ymin= -10,
ymax = 40,
legend style = {anchor = north west, at = {(1.05,1)}}
]
\addplot[thick,red]{x^3-x^2-1}
node[above,sloped,pos=0.85] {$r=1$};

\addplot[thick,blue]{x^12-x^11-1}
node[above,sloped,pos=0.5] {$r=10$};

\addplot[thick,magenta]{x^17-x^16-1}
node[above,sloped,pos=0.3] {$r=15$};

\addplot[thick,green]{x^22-x^21-1}
node[above,sloped,pos=0.06] {$r=20$};

\addplot[thick,cyan]{x^27-x^26-1}
node[above,sloped,pos=0.0126]{$r=25$};

\draw[loosely dotted] (0,0) -- (1.4,0);
\draw[dotted] (1,0) -- (1,40);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

    \subcaption{$f_r(x), x\in [0.9,1.4]$, for increasing $r$}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current axis.south)]
  \begin{axis}
    [xmin=.9,xmax=2,
      ymax=1,
      ymin=-.1,
      xlabel = $x$
    ]
    \addplot[thick,black,samples=100,domain=0:2] {x^2 - x}
    node[above,sloped,pos=.5] {$x^2 - x$}
    ;
    \addplot[thick,red,samples=100,domain=1:2]  {1/x}
    node[above,sloped,pos=.4] {$r=1$}
    ;
    \addplot[thick,blue,samples=100,domain=.99:2]  {1/x^10}
    node[above,sloped,pos=.3] {$r=10$}
    ;
    \addplot[thick,teal,samples=200,domain=.99:2]  {1/x^50}
    node[above,sloped,pos=.52] {$r=50$}
    ;
    \addplot[thick,brown,samples=300,domain=.99:2]  {1/x^200}
    ;
    \node[brown,rotate=270] at (axis cs:.96,.2) {$r=200$};
    \draw [black, fill=white]  (1.46557,0.682325) circle (3pt) node[right] {$I_1$};
    \draw [black, fill=white]  (1.17295,0.202862) circle (3pt) node[right] {$I_{10}$};
    \draw [black, fill=white]  (1.05757,0.060884) circle (3pt) node[right] {$I_{50}$};
    \draw [black, fill=white]  (1.03,0.035) circle (3pt) node[below] {$I_{200}$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \subcaption{Intersection points $I_r=(\rho_r,g_1(\rho_r))$ of $g_1(x):=x^2-x$ and $g_2(x):=x^{-r}$ for increasing $r$}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{$\rho_r\to 1$ as $r\to\infty$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, I added this Information and I Wonder Why the one word I typed before the figure environment appears in one own column. Maybe this is the origin of the problem: that the figure seems to start a new column.

Comment: I added a version of the example without all the packages not needed for the example but as appeared to be the case, the tikz look the same in the version at the bottom, outside of multicolumn and outside minipage, there did not appear to be anything in your code that would be affected by them? did you have these working in the poster class or in a more normal document class?

Comment: I added the Code for the case for which it works. This is class scrartcl.

Comment: so that's it then: it's unrelated to multicol/minipage simply that the font setup in the poster class is somewhat non standard and so you need to use smaller fonts in your tikz

Comment: Could you please tell me how to do that? Unfortunately, I have no experience how to change the font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The poster class uses big fonts, you need

```
 \begin{figure}[H]
 \centering\tiny
            %%%%
```

to get

[image]

This is unrelated to `multicol` or `minipage`.

Comment: By the way: Is it possible to make both pictures a bit larger?

Comment: @Rhjg `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]` ?